# Ubuntu 18.04 - "Activation of network connection failed Ubuntu"

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn

I have [IPVanish](https://www.ipvanish.com/) as my VPN provider, and usually I could connect without problem to almost all of their servers with Ubuntu 18.04.

But since a couple weeks, every time I try to log into their VPN, I get the following notification:

> Activation of network connection failed Ubuntu

I am quite unsure as what do to from this point, since as you see there is not a lot of feedback from the system.

Does anyone has an idea what could I do to solve it?

**Footnote**: I know I do not provided much info, but it is all I got. If you need any additional information to debug this case, please add it on the comments and I will dump the terminal output right away.

**Update 1**: I already tried contacting the provider. They keep sending me emails, but they seem quite lost.

**Update 2**: The configuration of the VPNs is done automatically by importing a `.ovpn` file. I tried deleting all the existing ones, and reset them from scratch, and it did not help.

**Update 3**: They use OpenVPN.

Comment: I would contact the VPN provider first.

Comment: I assume they're saying it's not from their side. Have you tried reconfiguring the connection?

Comment: The configuration is done 100% from their configuration files. I downloaded from their site a ZIP file with over 1000 files with extension `.ovpn`. I tried deleting all my already-created VPNs and re-create them from scratch. It did not help.

Comment: So it uses OpenVPN. (A shot in the dark as they say in the US): Try reinstalling the openVPN support: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall openvpn easy-rsa`.

Comment: That didnt't do anything :(

Comment: :( I'm really sorry, I have nothing else to suggest.

Comment: What command are you using to start VPN with the .ovpn file, or are you importing it? I assume that you're running a wired ethernet connection... does it work reliably, or does it also have problems without the VPN? Can you edit your question to include the VPN log? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I already solved the problem myself, and posted the answer. Apparently the path to the `.crt` file cannot contains spaces. Weird...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the solution looking at the syslog

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Apparently the .crt file with the certificate was inside a folder with spaces in the name, and that was causing the error. The moment I removed the spaces from the path to the file, it worked on the first try.

Weird bug, but it solved it.

Comment: I ran into a similar problems after I changed my username, and this helped me realize that was the issue.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had many Wi-Fi configured that were not available at time hence showing error, just disabled the Wi-Fi and open Wi-Fi at the use of time.
Problem solved.

Comment: I do not see the link between your answer and the idea of Enrique (remove spaces in a directory name).  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the password was changed (expired) and I had to update user password in the NetworkManager

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Enrique's answer: after consulting `var/log/syslog` I discovered that problem was that I'd configured serveral **bluetooth** devices ... none of which were available.  The "network connection failed" message was triggered every time network manager attempted to connect to one of these devices.

Solution: any one of these:

- Turn off bluetooth on your computer
- Remove the bluetooth config for the non-responsive device
- Reconnect the bluetooth device which was failing

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question due to the title.  My problem was not the OP's (I got this error with no VPN), but I will log my solution in case others come here like me.

I found my network card was correctly connected to a nearby switch (both ends showing the "link light")... however **that switch itself was not connected to the upstream switch**.

I surmise this error was being raise because the DHCP server could not be reached.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after a power restored after an outage, my switch rebooted before my router. So I needed to restart my switch after router rebooted.

PC <--> switch <--> router <--> internet

Answer (score 0):

I was on a corporate network with a static connection and proxy.
Running `sudo /var/log/syslog` showed `dhcp4 (eno1): request timed out`

Fixed by setting IPv4 settings below on Wired network connection (Network → Wired → Gear Icon → IPv4 → Manual → Addresses)
Address: XX.XX.XXX.XXX
Netmask: XXX.XXX.XXX.X
Gateway: XX.XX.XXX.X
DNS: XX.XX.XXX.XXX, XX.XX.XXX.XXX

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a .conf file with the VPN settings and maybe certificates and keys then don't delete those files after you set it up. They are looked up every time you connect.