# Activation of network connection failed in Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet

I have a dual booted system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I can easily connect to my home WiFi with Windows but with Ubuntu I get the following error:

```
Activation of network connection failed.
```

My home WiFi is protected with mac filter and I have added the mac address of my pc.

I tried solution of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087194/ubuntu-18-04-activation-of-network-connection-failed-ubuntu) post with no luck.

One thing I noticed when I turn off my WiFi in ubuntu the system turns on Flight mode automatically and when I turn off Flight mode bluetooth gets turned on.

I know I didn't post much info the reason being I am new to ubuntu so don't know what else to include please help.

**Edit:**

As requested in comments (command: `lspci -knn | grep Network -A3`):

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

command: `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be && sudo modprobe rtl8723be` print nothing

and command `rfkill list` prints following:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

tried second time and got this as output:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

note that I can connect to my mobile internet through hotspot without any problem.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `lspci -knn | grep Network -A3` then **edit your question above** and copy&paste the result in there.

Comment: edited my question with your requested command plus add some more info check it out

Comment: @darth_epoxy do you need anything else ?

Comment: After a reboot, immediately open a terminal and type `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be && sudo modprobe rtl8723be` and it that doesn't fire up then post the result of `rfkill list` for us.

Comment: edited see the output

Comment: Looks like it is timing out whle trying to connect to your modem or router. I have had the same problem with mac's and the modprobe worked for me. Using the gui Settings/Wi-Fi can you see your modem in the Visible Connections list? Even after it times out and throws the "Activation of network connection failed.." error on screen?

Comment: I cannot see the name of my WiFi because its hidden so i have to click on "connect to hidden nerwork"  and then type the name and password of my WiFi. But once I click on connect after that It trys to connect but after few seconds it throws an error "Activation of network connection failed" and then the WiFi name disappears from the connection list after throwing the error.

Comment: I think I should replace this ubuntu with the newer version maybe that would fix the problem but I fear it would corrupt my windows installation since i am in dual boot mode.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to go over router settings and then match Ubuntu network settings with them.

You can also try using BSSID to connect instead of network name.
more here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-hidden.html.en

I am note sure what is the benefit of hiding the network. See also the note in official documentation in the link i posted.

Can you connect to any other wi-fi network? That way at least you would know that wi-fi driver is not the issue. though based on bluetooth/flight mode behaviour i would say something is off.

newer version of Ubuntu would bring in new kernel that might have this driver built in or a newer tested version of driver (i am assuming here you had to patch 18.04 kernel to get the chip working.). but if you use 18.04 HWE stack you will get new kernel that was ported to 18.04.
you can read more about HWE here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack